# Date Extraction from a specific dataset - Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've tried all types of date extraction from this timestamp but nothing works.

Data samples:

1. Mon 2021 Jul 26 2021 8:26 PM
2. Wed May 19 2021 22:54:00 GMT+0800 (Hong Kong Standard Time)

Tried MOD, = Time,Minute, and Timevalue

Does anyone have any idea?

Tried MOD, = Time,Minute, and Timevalue. Expected to extract the date but it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(TEXT(IFNA(1*REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(A1:A), 
 "(\w+ \d+ \d{4})" ), "​"), "dd/mm/e"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `regexextract()`, like this:

`=to_date( value( regexextract( to_text(A2), "^\w+ (\w+ \w+ \w+)" ) ) )`